# Which grouping will be affected on Average in Elastic?

Tags: database, elasticsearch, request

I'm new in Elastic and just want to make sure if my thoughts where right.. 
In my Query i have added two groupings
"field": "statement.actor","field": "statement.type"
does the

```
avg:{"field": "statement.scaled}
```

refer to

```
"field": "statement.actor"
```

or to

```
"field": "statement.type"
```

QUERY:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "5": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "statement.type",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "_term": "desc"
        },
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "3": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "statement.actor",
            "size": 10,
            "order": {
              "_term": "desc"
            },
            "min_doc_count": 1
          },
          "aggs": {
            "1": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "statement.scaled"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```